# BLE Advertisement scan in javascript

Tags: javascript, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, navigator

Scanning of advertisements from nearby Bluetooth Low Energy Devices is my priority.
The code which i tried,requested the devices(it wanted to pair to get the characteristics). 
But my use case was to listen to their advertisements. For which I found this code

```
function recordNearbyBeacon(major, minor, pathLossVs1m) { ... }
navigator.bluetooth.requestLEScan({
  filters: [{manufacturerData: {0x004C: {dataPrefix: new Uint8Array([
    0x02, 0x15, // iBeacon identifier.
    0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15  // My beacon UUID.
  ])}}}],
  options: {
    keepRepeatedDevices: true,
  }
}).then(() => {
  navigator.bluetooth.addEventListener('advertisementreceived', event => {
    let appleData = event.manufacturerData.get(0x004C);
    if (appleData.byteLength != 23) {
      // Isn’t an iBeacon.
      return;
    }
    let major = appleData.getUint16(18, false);
    let minor = appleData.getUint16(20, false);
    let txPowerAt1m = -appleData.getInt8(22);
    let pathLossVs1m = txPowerAt1m - event.rssi;

    recordNearbyBeacon(major, minor, pathLossVs1m);
  });
})
```

There are certain uuids in the official site which i tried but none seem to work.
I want to get the characteristic values from the advertisement data. How to get the data in Javascript? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [implementation status](https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/web-bluetooth/blob/master/implementation-status.md#scanning-api) document from the Web Bluetooth GitHub, the [Web Bluetooth Scanning API](https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/web-bluetooth/blob/master/implementation-status.md#scanning-api) (which is what provides the `requestLEScan` method) is not yet implemented in any browser.

Comment: Thank. Is there any alternative in Javascript in browser to read advertisements from beacon without pairing?

Comment: Sadly, nothing that I know of.